# Finding a function, so that x is the only minimum

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

> Let x' be the unique solution of the linear system Ax=b. Find a differentiable function , so that x' is the only minimum.

I would say $f(x) = (x-x')^2$ but I never use the property of x' so that doesn't seem right. I was thinking of something like $f(x)=A^{-1}b$ but how do I know that A is invertible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x'$ is the unique solution of the linear system $Ax = b$, then $A$ is invertible.

---

A function such that $x'$ is the unique minimum build up using both $A$ and $b$ is:

$$f(x) = (Ax - b)^\top(Ax-b) = \\
=x^\top A^\top A x - 2b^\top Ax + b^\top b.$$

Differentiating, you get:

$$\frac{df}{dx} = 2A^\top A x - 2A^\top b = 2A^\top(Ax - b),$$

which is null for $x = x'$ (indeed $Ax'-b = 0$).

Notice also that the Hessian matrix is $$H = 2A^\top A,$$
which is positive definite, and hence all its eigenvalues are positive $\Rightarrow x'$ is the unique minimum.